# Verify if the argv 1 have a determined value

Tags: c

**Problem**

I've this simple script to verify the argv. The problem is that if I try to input the argv 1 to "-help" it don't print the string "banner". Why it is not printing the string?

I think that is important to say that I'm noobie with the C language.

**Script**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[ ]){
    int cont;

    printf("argv 1 -> %s", argv[1]);

    if(argv[1] == "-help"){
        printf("banner");
    }

    if(("%s", argv[1]) == "-help"){
        printf("banner");
    }

//main
}
```

Comment: check out strcmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[1] == "-help"` is comparing pointers, not the contents of strings. It will never be true because it is comparing variable region and fixed region.

`("%s", argv[1]) == "-help"` has the same meaning with `argv[1] == "-help"`. `,` here is a *comma operator*.

You should use [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare strings in C. Also don't forget to check if `argv[1]` has meaningful value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]){

    if (argc >= 2) {
        printf("argv 1 -> %s", argv[1]);

        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-help") == 0){
            printf("banner");
        }
    }

//main
}
```

Comment: I've a question: the 0 of "(strcmp(argv[1], "-help") == 0)" meaning if "(strcmp(argv[1], "-help")" is true?

Comment: `0` means that the strings are equal, regardless of the truth of `strcmp(argv[1], "-help")`.